# Failed adding runner deploy key to GitLab project

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

After adding a project in the gitlab CI, I got:

> You should assign at least one runner to project for processing
>   project builds. Visit this page to assign runner

The linked page (**/ci/projects/16/runner_projects**) had a button to add a runner to the project, but When I hit the `Add` , I got the error:

> Failed adding runner deploy key to GitLab project

Gitlab Version:

- GitLab CI 3.2.0 e0c0609
- Gitlab 6.2

Comment: Are you use Add or Assign to All? I am in C# chat room if you want to avoid a lot of comments.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all SSH keys from your profile on GitLab, and then it will let you add the runner to the project.

Answer (score 0):

A [similar issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/246) does mention a workaround:

> it may be good to note exactly what will and won't work for adding a gitlab-ci-runner.
>
> I was able to get this to work by creating a new user and creating a `gitlab-ci-runner` with-in that.
>
> Previously I had tried adding a runner that was running under an existing user, once using that user's main ssh key (which was also added to my account in my instance of gitlabhq).
> I then tried it using a newly generated key used just for the gitlab-ci-runner.

This is a bit similar to [issue 204](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/204), where the problem exists for both "Add" and "Assign to all", with a potential cause:

> I think my issue is that I was trying to add my key when it already existed on a project... I can successfully add new keys just fine.

As [issue 207](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/207) mentions:

> Runner should be registered on GItLab CI url. not GitLab (ie: use http://ci.gitlab.org)

Make sure that your version of gitlab-ci at least include [commit 9aca33e](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/commit/9aca33e) (from your question, it should be the case).

Answer (score -1):

You have to fill all the information in the "Advanced settings" section on CI project's edit page

Comment: I see. But all the "Advanced settings" are auto filled with the correct information excpet Toke(Leave empty to generate random token).